# Cmake executable can not link with the new interface library depending on another library

Tags: cmake

I have the following dependencies:

```
add_library(lib)
add_library(ilib INTERFACE)
add_dependencies(ilib lib)
target_link_libraries(ilib INTERFACE
      "-Wl,--whole-archive $<TARGET_FILE:lib> Wl,--no-whole-archive")
add_executable(exe ilib)
```

When I changed some source codes of `lib`, the lib as expected was compiled and built again. However, `exe` did not link the new `lib`. If I use `add_executable(exe lib)`, then `exe` will always link the new `lib`. (The reason why I use the `ilib` is that I need to process `lib` before using it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `lib` to be propagated when one links with `ilib`.

But command `add_dependencies` doesn't add properties for propagation. You need

```
# Linking with `ilib` will transitively link with a `lib`
target_link_libraries(ilib INTERFACE lib)
```

When need to use `--whole-archive` option for linker, it could be done in the following way:

```
target_link_libraries(ilib INTERFACE "-Wl,--whole-archive" lib "Wl,--no-whole-archive")
```

When parse arguments for given function, CMake will finds argument `lib` to be a **target name**, and will add proper **file-level** dependency. With that dependency the executable will be relinked whenever the library file has been changed.

Comment: Sorry, I had  `target_link_libraries(ilib INTERFACE lib)` in my cmake script, but forgot to present it here. So this also doesn't work. Please see my new update.

Comment: Hm, you actually has more complex call that `target_link_libraries(ilib INTERFACE lib)`. Have you tried exactly this, simple call?

Comment: You're right. I tried exactly this and it worked as expected. Is there a solution to make my scripts right?

Comment: As far I recall, using `--whole-archive` in CMake could be done as `-Wl,--whole-archive lib Wl,--no-whole-archive`. The difference with your code is that given code doesn't group the whole expression as a single argument (double quotes are removed). Instead, it provides 3 arguments, and the second one is a **target name**, which should cause a proper file-level dependency.

Comment: After removing the double quotes, everything is OK. Thanks very much. Besides, my script is based on the caffe2_interface_library macro from https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/cmake/public/utils.cmake.

Comment: I have updated the answer post with `--whole-archive` example.